# Django delete&update view only for owner

Tags: python, django, django-views

I'm writing some task for my university in Django.In my update&delete view I want to make sure that only an owner of object can update/delete it. Now everyone can do it.

Here are views:

```
class UpdateCar(SuccessMessageMixin, UpdateView):
    model = Car
    form_class = AddNewCarForm
    template_name = 'c2crental/car/update_car.html'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('c2crental:list_user_cars')
    success_message = _("Car has been updated.")

    def get_queryset(self):
        owner = self.request.user
        return self.model.objects.filter(owner=owner)


class DeleteCar(DeleteView):
    model = Car
    success_url = reverse_lazy('c2crental:list_user_cars')
    template_name = 'c2crental/car/delete_confirm_car.html'
    success_message = _("Car has been deleted.")

    def delete(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        messages.success(self.request, self.success_message)
        return super(DeleteCar, self).delete(request, *args, **kwargs)

    def get_queryset(self):
        owner = self.request.user
        return self.model.objects.filter(owner=owner)
```

I found some solutions with querysets as shown above. They won't let other Users update/delete an object and raise Http404 error which is fine, but I want to use Django messages framework to print error message on page and dont redirect to Http404 page. How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do this by overriding the [`dispatch`](https://ccbv.co.uk/projects/Django/2.0/django.views.generic.edit/UpdateView/#dispatch) or [`get_object`](https://ccbv.co.uk/projects/Django/2.0/django.views.generic.edit/UpdateView/#get_object) methods on your views.

As you'll see, if the `get_object` doesn't find an object, it throws a 404, so if you don't match the owner you could throw a 403 or 404.

```
def get_object(self, queryset=None):
    """
    Check the logged in user is the owner of the object or 404
    """
    obj = super(MyView, self).get_object(queryset)
    if obj.owner != self.request.user:
        raise Http404(
            _("You don't own this object")
        )
    return obj
```

Comment: I see, but how can I print Http404 message using Django messages as error instead redirecting to new page?

Comment: Well you wouldn't want to stay on the page if someone isn't authorised surely? Just add `messages.error(self.request, self.error_message)` before the `raise` to add the message to the request.